# Opening and closing an app using the Widget on Samsung Smart TVs?

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

I want my app to be able to be opened and closed at will by the end user.

I'd like it to be the first thing on screen when the TV turns on, which is one of the reasons I'm using the Widget/H-Browser mode. But I also want the user to be able to exit my app and use the TV as they normally would. So far, the only thing I've seen is this command:

```
widgetAPI.sendExitEvent();
```

So I thought, maybe if there is a way to exit the app, there might be a way to re-enter it on some keypress event. Ideas?

If I can't open and close the app, does anyone happen to know if/how I can play the TV channels from within the app?

Comment: In general Samsung Smart TV platform you don't have solution for autostart your widget. And if you exit from app you can't restart app.

Comment: Happen to know if there is a way to play video from the different channels within a widget?

Answer (score 0):

> "If I can't open and close the app, does anyone happen to know if/how I can play the TV
>   channels from within the app?"

You can't in Europe. Samsung does not allow ticker apps(IE apps that overlay a video broadcast) in EU. You could do this if you were in the US. The reason for this is that the broadcaster might not want his content covered by a third party application. So its not allowed at all in Europe, with a few exceptions if the broadcasted content and the app are from the same content provider.